# Web view page is not displaying below android 5.0 version but working in 5.1.1 , only blank screen is showing in 4.4.2

Tags: android, google-chrome, user-interface, url, android-webview

Web view URL is working fine in android 5.1.1 but not in 4.4.2 version , its displaying blank screen only. Here is my code

```
public class WebViewTwo extends Activity {
WebView webView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.web_view_two);
    webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView2);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.loadUrl("www.google.co.in");
}
```

Here is my logcat error

```
07-21 12:26:13.053    2089-2104/com.ccc.dar E/eglCodecCommon﹕ glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
07-21 12:26:13.064    2089-2104/com.ccc.dar E/eglCodecCommon﹕ glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
07-21 12:26:13.167    2089-2104/com.ccc.dar E/eglCodecCommon﹕ **** ERROR unknown type 0x79edaef5 (glSizeof,72)
07-21 12:26:13.184    2089-2104/com.ccc.dar E/eglCodecCommon﹕ glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
07-21 12:26:13.194    2089-2104/com.ccc.dar E/eglCodecCommon﹕ glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
07-21 12:26:13.214    2089-2096/com.ccc.dar W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 22.429ms
07-21 12:26:13.238    2089-2104/com.ccc.dar E/eglCodecCommon﹕ **** ERROR unknown type 0x79edaef5 (glSizeof,72)
07-21 12:26:13.435    2089-2104/com.ccc.dar E/eglCodecCommon﹕ glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
07-21 12:26:13.457    2089-2104/com.ccc.dar E/eglCodecCommon﹕ glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
07-21 12:26:13.499    2089-2101/com.ccc.dar I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1125(118KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(16KB) LOS objects, 0% free, 5MB/5MB, paused 2.405ms total 145.580ms
07-21 12:26:13.584    2089-2104/com.ccc.dar E/eglCodecCommon﹕ **** ERROR unknown type 0x79edaef5 (glSizeof,72)
07-21 12:26:44.980    2089-2096/com.ccc.dar W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 11.554ms
```

Comment: When i have tried any url only blank screen is displaying..

Comment: I have tried many times but its not getting solution what will be the problem ? is it API problem, browser problem etc suggest me , i have tried as like that Please solve it thanks in advance..

Comment: Actually I have physical device Samsung tab but its only URL is not loading..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After research I got my answer and now its running smoothly on 4.4.2.

```
public class WebViewTwo extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.web_view_two);

    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView2);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());

    webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.co.in");
}

private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace code  webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); with  webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
Add following code -

```
private class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

        @Override
        public void onConsoleMessage(String message, int lineNumber, String sourceID) {
            Log.d(TAG, message + " -- From line "
                    + lineNumber + " of "
                    + sourceID);
        }
    }
```

check the console log.
And also check whether your url is with http or https , so can handle accordingly.
it is also happened with me once and issue was found of webpage.

Comment: yes I have http url and what is this on TAG can not resolve symbol is displaying why?

Comment: @Arman Tag is just a string you can pass any string instead of TAG like. "MyWebChromeClient"

Comment: Please explain about this (TAG, message + " -- From line "
                    + lineNumber + " of "
                    + sourceID);

Comment: @Arman Place the code and run the app,check the log to see what console message shows for that url.

Comment: @Arman It is use to get the output which can help to webdeveloper if error is from webpage-
Message : It shows the exception
Line Number : Line number of webpage where exception occure

Comment: 07-21 12:26:13.584    2089-2104/com.ccc.dar E/eglCodecCommon﹕ **** ERROR unknown type 0x79edaef5 (glSizeof,72)
07-21 12:26:44.980    2089-2096/com.ccc.dar W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 11.554ms

Comment: in log cat something displaying like that screen is blank when loading url

Comment: Defilnatly, it might be some help :)

Comment: @NirishSrivastava have u found issue I have edited with log cat error

Comment: @Arman I have looked the logcat you added but it is not relevant.

Comment: Thanks for Your effort @NitishSrivastava