# Android Webview crashes on android 4.4 while opening external url

Tags: android, webview

I am developing an application where I am using a webview. Everything is working fine but when I try to open external links inside webview it either freezes or crashes.This happens on android 4.4 and below but works well on android 5.0 and above.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    ///initialize webview
    private WebView mwebview;
    ProgressBar bar;
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        mwebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebview);
        bar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
        WebSettings webSettings = mwebview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mwebview.loadUrl("http://stalls.co.ke/shopping");

        // improve webview perfomance

        mwebview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            mwebview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        } else {
            mwebview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }

        mwebview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        mwebview.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setSavePassword(true);
        webSettings.setSaveFormData(true);
        webSettings.setEnableSmoothTransition(true);

        //force links to open in webview only
        mwebview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());



        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }




    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
            // Handle the camera action
            mwebview.loadUrl("http://stalls.co.ke/shopping");
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gifts) {
            mwebview.loadUrl("http://stalls.co.ke/gifts-coupons");


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_men) {

            mwebview.loadUrl("http://stalls.co.ke/stallswear-men");

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_women) {

            mwebview.loadUrl("http://stalls.co.ke/stallswear-women");

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_kids) {

            mwebview.loadUrl("http://stalls.co.ke/stallswear-kids-baby");

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_men_cosmetics) {

            mwebview.loadUrl("http://stalls.co.ke/copy-of-stalls-cosmetics");

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_women_cosmetics) {

            mwebview.loadUrl("http://stalls.co.ke/copy-of-men-footwear");

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_kids_cosmetics) {

            mwebview.loadUrl("http://stalls.co.ke/copy-of-stalls-cosmetics");

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_homes) {

            mwebview.loadUrl("http://stalls.co.ke/home-kitchen-products");

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_garden) {

            mwebview.loadUrl("http://stalls.co.ke/garden-products");

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_smarthomes) {

            mwebview.loadUrl("http://stalls.co.ke/smart-home-products");

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_eatery) {

            mwebview.loadUrl("http://stalls.co.ke/stallseatery");


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_customer_service) {

            mwebview.loadUrl("http://stalls.co.ke/help");

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_about_us) {

            mwebview.loadUrl("http://stalls.co.ke/about-us");

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_kijo) {

            mwebview.loadUrl("http://stalls.co.ke/house-of-kinjo");

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_Airi) {

            mwebview.loadUrl("http://stalls.co.ke/Airi");

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_mamapeter) {

            mwebview.loadUrl("http://stalls.co.ke/house-of-kinjo");

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_swahili) {

            mwebview.loadUrl("http://stalls.co.ke/swahili-princess");

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_allstalls) {

            mwebview.loadUrl("http://stalls.co.ke/kenyan-stores");

        }








        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    public Action getIndexApiAction() {
        Thing object = new Thing.Builder()
            .setName("Main Page") // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated URL is correct.
            .setUrl(Uri.parse("http://[ENTER-YOUR-URL-HERE]"))
            .build();
        return new Action.Builder(Action.TYPE_VIEW)
            .setObject(object)
            .setActionStatus(Action.STATUS_TYPE_COMPLETED)
            .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, getIndexApiAction());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, getIndexApiAction());
        client.disconnect();
    }


    // go to previous page when back button is pressed

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if (mwebview.canGoBack()) {
                        mwebview.goBack();
                    } else {
                        finish();
                    }
                    return true;

            }
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            bar.setVisibility(view.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                mwebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                            view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            } else {
                mwebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                        view.loadUrl(url);
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my `MainActivity.java` file, I would like to know why this is happening.

Comment: Show your logcat

Comment: Please try to replace your MainActivity code with a [Minimum, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @HeikkiMäenpää what do you mean?i am abit new to this platform and android development.

Comment: May be Similar to this Please check it [This happens on android 4.4 and below but works well on android 5.0 and above.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38451360/any-url-is-not-loading-using-web-view-below-5-0-version-but-its-fine-in-5-1-1-an)

Comment: @KennedyOkiya Try including www like this ...www.stalls... along with existing existing URL, than http://stalls.co.ke/shopping

Comment: @Stallion where exactly do you intend i put the 'www'?Coz adding that on the  mwebview.loadUrl("http://stalls.co.ke/shopping") will not load the site inside webview as i have tried that and it did not load.

Comment: I'm asking you to write a small program demonstrating your problem, and post the code of that into your question. You may end up discovering what the problem is in the process, and if you don't people will be more likely to take the time and read that and offer their insights than they are the current 300 line code.

Comment: I am using "+" symbol in this comment,  as SO automatically converts into URL format. But you can try without "+" symbol and just include www .Make your URL as http + : + www + // + stalls.co.ke + / + shopping

Answer (score 0):

try using WebChromeClient; instead of WebViewClient; see if it works.